# grails 4 development dynamic reloading gets steadily slower

Tags: grails

Grails 4 seems to progressively deteriorate  in its ability to hot reload while developing. 
After making changes to a file while the app is running in development mode, the recompile gets slower and slower after each change and save.

After about a half dozen changes, the time to reload goes from seconds to minutes.

Eventually, it is faster to shut it down and run-app again.

I'm on windows, and the app uses Spring security.

Curious if anyone else has experienced this issue and what can be done to mitigate it.